# How to make an important unary minus stand out in code?

Tags: java, operators, readability

I have an entity that represents a reservation of some quantity. There will also exist entities where this property is negative indicating a lack of availability for the reservation. The logic will then decrease the quantity of a reservation with a positive quantity property value. Therefore I have this statement:

```
long quantityToDecrease = -reservation.getQuantity();
```

How can I make the unary minus stand out so that the reader of my code will be aware of it?

Comment: Make a well named method that will only return `-reservation.getQuantity();` and use that instead. I.e. `quantityToDecrease = notAvailable(reservation);`.

Comment: You can always add comments.

Comment: Put a zero in front of it, or a comment, or both. Don't follow the inane advice to implement a separate method: that would be the first thing I would remove in a code review. In any case it only shifts the problem.

Comment: maybe it is not important to point it out because pointing out how the code works for a single step like this is not important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the inline comment and empty lines around it:

```
// note the unary minus
long quantityToDecrease = -reservation.getQuantity();
```

But I also do find the solution suggested by @Kayaman appealing, because it makes the code read more like the busines logic is described.

Answer (score -1):

To make it really stand out you can make a seperate method and maybe in a seperate class:

`long quantityToDecrease = negate(reservation.getQuantity());`

It may look like over kill, but I think this way you will get the readers attention the best.

Also if you use this in a lot of places maybe you can write your own `NumberUtil` class or something in that direction, where you can define your negate method in. Making it something like:

`long quantityToDecrease = NumberUtil.negate(reservation.getQuantity());`